# On click, show() content below selected element's row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

What I'm trying to do is build a team page. Similar to http://www.razorfish.com/people/ourpeople.htm

I want to create a floated or inline row of elements, and show hidden content within each inline element UNDER the selected element. Thus, moving the next row further down. 
However, I'm a newbie to JavaScript.

This is what I have now: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LF7hy/5/)

```
// var tag = $(this).parent().find(".hidden-info");
// var prevStyle = tag.attr('style');

$('.profile-header').click(function(){

//$('.hidden-info').show();
$(this).parent().find(".hidden-content").toggle();
//return false;

$(this).parent().find(".hidden-content").append(".people");
$(this).parent().find(".hidden-content").css("position","relative", "z-index","99");

});
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to go about achieving this?

Comment: If you view source on that razorfish page, `/js/people.js` has all the answers you need. You can quickly deobfuscate it...

Comment: I tried, but I guess I can keep tinkering with it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than traversing the DOM using `.parent()` and `.find()`, you can simply specify the selector context:

```
$('.profile-header').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        hidden_content = $(".hidden-content", $this);

    hidden_content.toggle().toggleClass("people");
});
```

Your `append` as written won't do anything. If you are trying to change its class, you should consider using `addClass` or `toggleClass` instead and add your CSS to the new class rather than changing your CSS in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Place a `.people-data` div under each row of people. on each people click, find the `.people-data` that corresponds to that row and populate it with data.

```
$('.profile-header').parent().find('.people-data') // populate and show
```

Edit:

If you want it to be responsive, place the `.people-data` under each person and expand it the same way you would a row. This will work if you have each person item `display:inline-block`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would want this team section to be responsive. So if I put a ".people-data" under each row, it wouldn't quite work correctly right?

Comment: I made an edit. You'll have to mess around with how to show the div, but if you increase the height of each person item, anything `block` below it move down.

Answer (score 0):

The key changes are:

- Setting `display: none;` instead of `float: left;` to the `li`'s
- Setting `position: absolute;` and `left: 0px;` to the `.hidden-content`
- Setting the selected `li`'s height programatically to pull the next line down
- Toggling the previously selected `li`'s to hide old detailing section

[See working fiddle sample here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vZfab/1/)

Comment: Yo! Thank you, that's pretty much what I needed. I found one small issue, I'm trying to figure out but you might be able to faster. I noticed that the bottom row doesn't shift down properly when clicking around on the links a lot.